# create multiple cells in a loop in notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have a dictionary with list of data as values and want to plot all of them separately (not in a single plot), how to proceed with this?

**example variable:**

```
employees = {"age": [...], "experience": [...], "qualification": [...], "salary": [...], ...}
```

I do have a function to plot a histogram via matplotlib: `plotHist`.
The only method currently I can follow is to create multiple cells and in each cell plot one of the keys of `employees` manually.

Is there a way to loop over the keys of `employees` and plot them separately in different cells? 
(or)
In a single cell, output multiple plots separately (not subplots.) without the interactive mode of matplotlib in Jupyter notebook?

Comment: So you want a code that puts a plot of `age` in a cell, then another new cell that has the plot of `experience`, and so on? Suppose that the `employees` has only 4 inner arrays: `age`, `experience`, `qualification`, and `salary`. Do you want to create a cell for each of them and create plot with only the code from another code cell?

Comment: @DhanaD. kind of yes. or if that's not possible, then the 2nd question.